# Database.db file in Macintosh HD

Tags: macos

I see a Database.db file with size zero bytes on my Macintosh HD

Is this a system file? i am not sure if this is something i can remove or the purpose of this file

Regards

Comment: Where is the file?

Comment: That's what I am wondering I am new to OS X so always want to be careful

Comment: You have the disk so only you can provide the full path to the file

Comment: i am sorry Mark, mind plays trick sometime, I read your comment as what is this file

Comment: This is sitting in / drive

Comment: What does `ls -l@e /Database.db` show

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 companyname  admin  0 Jul  4  2011 Databases.db i think my company put this file here. it could be pushed via Group Policy or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably fine, but it depends and since it's taking up no space, no good reason to delete it yet. It's simply a database file put there by something (again, probably not OS X.) You should attempt to narrow down what application is using the file (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317177/see-what-process-is-using-a-file-in-mac-os-x)) and then either keep it or delete it as appropriate.